# Rails join query based on associated records column value

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I have two models:

**Project**

```
attributes: id, status (open, cancelled, reopened)
has_many: todos
```

**Todo**

```
attributes: id, project_id, status (done, partially_done, pending)
belongs_to: project
```

I have to tabs: `Done` and `Pending` In these two tabs I have to show projects based on associated todo status.

`Project.all.includes(:todos).where(todos: {status: ['done', 'partially_done']})`

It'll return Projects, where the associated todos are in done/partially_done status.

Let's say: I have two projects:

```
Project 1 -> Todo 1 (done), Todo 2 (partially_done), Todo 3 (pending)
Project 2 -> Todo 4 (done), Todo 5 (partially_done), Todo 6 (done)
```

In the `done` tab: it'll show only Project 2 (as all todos are done or partially done)

In the `pending` tab it'll show only Project 1 (as one todo is still in pending state)

How can I filter the projects based on todos?

I can do something like:

`pending_projects = Project.joins(:todos).select{|project| project.todos.any?(&:pending?)}`

But it seems time consuming. any way to do this effectively?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
pending_projects = Project.joins(:todos).where(todos: { status: :pending })
```

This way you cede all the job of finding proper records to DB engine, which is correct.

Comment: is it going to return projects as pending, where at least one todo is pending?

Comment: Yes, it's gonna do that.

Comment: Can I do something like this? 
`Project.joins(:todos).where(todos: { status: :pending  && status: ![:done, :partially_done]})`

Comment: you can use `where.not()` instead

Comment: `pending_projects = Project.joins(:todos).where(todos: { status: :pending }).where.not(todos: {status: [:done, :partially_done]})`

Comment: @Aparichith it's not gonna work as expected, since the row with joined `pending` todo record fulfill these conditions.